# Exibir select ASP.NET SqlServer

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Eu estou dando manutenção em 1 controller e estou pegando os dados do meu banco de dados e tentando exibir ele na view, porem eu não conseguindo passar o select para a view, alguem pode me ajudar?eu preciso passar todos os dados do select em uma tabela ou em texto normal.

Segue o codigo da minha controller:

```
        public ActionResult GetContacts()
    {
        SqlConnection conexao = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source="nomebd";Initial Catalog="nometabela";User ID="usuario";Password="senha"");
        conexao.Open();
        string strQuerySelect = "SELECT * FROM people where id > 0 and id < 100";

        SqlCommand cmdComandoSelect = new SqlCommand(strQuerySelect, conexao);
        SqlDataReader dados = cmdComandoSelect.ExecuteReader();

        var contacts = new List<OrderViewModel>();
        while (dados.Read())
        {
            contacts.Add(new OrderViewModel
            {
                id = dados["id"].ToString(),
                idPessoa = Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(dados["idPessoa"]) * 3.2, 2),
                Nome = dados["nome"].ToString(),
            });
        }

        return Json(contacts);
    }
```

Comment: Marcelo, você está tendo retorno dentro de contracts? coloca um break point e passa o mouse em cima, vê se existem itens dentro dele... Se sim eu consigo te ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Com sua View tipada você pode na sua Action dá um `return View(contacts);` e em seguida na sua View:

```
@model OrderViewModel
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div>
   Conteúdo da View
</div>
```

Sua Action alterada:

```
  public ActionResult GetContacts()
    {
        SqlConnection conexao = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source="nomebd";Initial Catalog="nometabela";User ID="usuario";Password="senha"");
        conexao.Open();
        string strQuerySelect = "SELECT * FROM people where id > 0 and id < 100";

        SqlCommand cmdComandoSelect = new SqlCommand(strQuerySelect, conexao);
        SqlDataReader dados = cmdComandoSelect.ExecuteReader();

        var contacts = new List<OrderViewModel>();
        while (dados.Read())
        {
            contacts.Add(new OrderViewModel
            {
                id = dados["id"].ToString(),
                idPessoa = Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(dados["idPessoa"]) * 3.2, 2),
                Nome = dados["nome"].ToString(),
            });
        }

        return View(contacts);
    }
```

Obs: "Quando você da um `return Json(...)` está dizendo especificamente ao MVC para não usar uma exibição e para servir dados JSON serializados"
Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15197674/4312593